# How do I get elements withou the second class name

Tags: javascript, html

Here is the code:

```
<p class="phar">phar</p>
<p class="phar no">phar</p>
<p class="phar no">phar</p>
<p class="phar">phar</p>
<p class="phar">phar</p>
```

How do I get elements with only the class name 'phar' without 'no' using only javascript?

Comment: Please Stack Overflow is not a free coding service, try something then post a question if you're having problems, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit use the `:not()` pseudo-class selector in a `querySelectorAll()` function:

```js
const els = document.querySelectorAll(".phar:not(.no)");
console.log([...els]);
```

```html
<p class="phar">phar</p>
<p class="phar no">phar</p>
<p class="phar no">phar</p>
<p class="phar">phar</p>
<p class="phar">phar</p>
```

Comment: I'm really sorry that I didn't say it beforehand. I need it to be done in pure javascript. Maybe you can help me with this one